# Making global variables persistent in bash shell

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to set  the environment variables `MAILPATH` and `MAIL` permanently 
(i.e. make them persistent)

I already tried the following:

```
MAILPATH=/home/don/Maildir
export MAILPATH
MAIL=Maildir
export MAIL
```

This needs to be done every time I start a new bash shell (i.e., open new terminal etc.)

How do I make these settings permanent? 
I have tried setting these variables in `/etc/environment` but that does not make them persistent.

Comment: A side note, /etc/environment file is for system wide settings. You don't want to have same MAILPATH or such other settings pointing to your home directory made available to other users. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: Please note that you can assign and export a shell environment variable in one single step: `export MAILPATH=/home/don/Maildir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it persistent by adding it to your `~/.bashrc` file. This file is called every time you start an interactive bash shell.