# how to make environment variables persist?

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables, system, administration

For this [bash](https://askubuntu.com/q/1205227/45156) script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export AccessToken=678
export AccessTokenSecret=wxy
export ApiKey=abc
export ApiSecret=123
```

How can I then ensure that `printenv` run at a later point in time will show these variables?  That is, how are they made persistent?

Must they be [added](https://askubuntu.com/q/825410/45156) to the `.bashrc` file?

I would think there's a sort of "database" of environment variables which can be accessed?

Comment: `/etc/environment` but r u looking for lacalization?

Comment: only care that when the script only has to run once, really.