# add bash script to /etc/profile.d/ to load variables?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables, powershell

As a follow-on to a `bash` question on [setting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment) environment variables, I see:

```
/etc/profile.d/*.sh

Files with the .sh extension in the /etc/profile.d directory get executed whenever a bash login shell is entered (e.g. when logging in from the console or over ssh), as well as by the DisplayManager when the desktop session loads.

You can for instance create the file /etc/profile.d/myenvvars.sh and set variables like this:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

such a [script](https://askubuntu.com/q/1205834/45156) as:

```
#!/bin/sh
export AccessToken=678
export AccessTokenSecret=wxy
export ApiKey=abc
export ApiSecret=123
```

can be safely added to `/etc/profile.d/` so that a powershell [script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59882280/262852) will pick up the variables?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Did you try it?

Comment: I'll add that, was more asking for safety's sake.   thx.