# how to run or re-load /etc/profile.d/ scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, .profile, virtual-console

From within the GUI, I'm seeing [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/438150/45156) result:

> My problem is exactly that this does not happen in the terminal run
>   under the graphical user interface; neither in Ubuntu 16.04.3 or
>   18.04. – Thomas Arildsen Oct 1 '18 at 11:57

for the `env.sh` script which I've added:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll /etc/profile.d/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 29 15:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 148 root root 12288 Aug 19 20:50 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    96 Aug  6  2018 01-locale-fix.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   825 Oct 15  2018 apps-bin-path.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   664 Apr  1  2018 bash_completion.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1003 Dec 29  2015 cedilla-portuguese.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   321 Jan 29 15:51 env.sh*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1024 Jan 29 15:51 .env.sh.swp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   687 Aug 23  2018 input-method-config.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1253 Dec 16  2018 rvm.sh*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1945 Oct 10  2018 vte-2.91.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   954 Oct  5  2018 xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh
thufir@dur:~$
```

However, switching to a virtual console and logging, I can run `printenv`, grep the results, and see [new variables as defined](https://askubuntu.com/q/1206270/45156) in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export AccessToken=678
export AccessTokenSecret=wxy
export ApiKey=abc
export ApiSecret=123
```

I've tried `source .bashrc` but that doesn't seem to run the scripts in `/etc/profile.d/`.  How can I re-load or run those from within the GUI?

I'm using gnome shell and bash; older system:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~$
```

and:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE 
x11
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: What's the name of the file? Which display manager are you using?

Comment: I'll check that out, `source /etc/profile.d/env.sh` works.

Comment: not sure what display manager.  unity?  default for whatever installed, pardn @GunnarHjalmarsson   the file is `env.sh` which I can source from the gui console.

Comment: @Thufir: No, I mean are you using LightDM, GDM or something else? The file name is ok - I just wondered if the `.sh` extension was there.

Comment: it's the `env.sh` file, @GunnarHjalmarsson; updated the q.  Not sure about LightDM or GDM, pardon, I'll have to look into that.  the GUI console is gnome terminal.

Comment: Files like `/etc/profile.d/foo.sh` are sourced by the default `/etc/profile` file - which is loaded for login shells like the one invoked when you log in at the CLI virtual console but not when a GUI terminal emulator invokes a non-login interactive shell (although at least for `gnome-terminal`, there's a checkbox to `Run command as a login shell`) .

Comment: @steeldriver: In graphical sessions, they are sourced by the display manager at login and made environment variables which are available through the whole session. See for instance `/etc/gdm3/Xsession`. (Not sure about Wayland in this respect, though.)

Comment: @Thufir: Then you most likely have GDM. Are you possibly using Wayland? You can check by running this command: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Comment: different OS, @GunnarHjalmarsson but it comes back as X 11